# Quartz FileScanJob - File Not Found

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

Here is my quartz.properties:

```
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 10
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
```

The jobs.xml resides in my */WEB-INF/classes* folder, alongside the quartz.properties folder.  The app is packaged as a war.

The jobs.xml file gets parsed correctly and creates the job:

```
13:49:30,158 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (MSC service thread 1-8) Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
13:49:30,172 INFO  [org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) Parsing XML file: jobs.xml with systemId: jobs.xml
13:49:30,403 INFO  [org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) Adding 1 jobs, 1 triggers.
13:49:30,403 INFO  [org.quartz.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) Adding job: MYJOB_GROUP.journal_report_job
```

However, I then start getting this in the log:

```
13:50:40,165 WARN  [org.quartz.jobs.FileScanJob] (ReportScheduler_Worker-2) File 'jobs.xml' does not exist.
```

Basically, XMLSchedulingDataProcessor is able to find jobs.xml, but FileScanJob is not.

I would like to leave jobs.xml inside the WAR if possible as it makes the app easy to install and maintain due to all the necessary files being in one package.  But FileScanJob seems to be unable to handle this.

So how can I change the value of the org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames property so that both XMLSchedulingDataProcessor and FileScanJob can make sense of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the name to `classpath:jobs.xml`

Comment: Hi, have you solved the problem? I meet the same problem.....